# Why did not delete data table records in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

in Laravel 5.6 application I have following Controller function to delete vehicle table records,

```
public function deleteOneAd($id)
    {
 DB::table('vehicles')
            ->where('id', $id)

            ->delete();
 return redirect()->back();
```

my delete button link is,

```
href="/myads/{{$vehicule->id}}/delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to want to delete this record?')" >Delete</a></td>
```

and route for delete,

```
Route::get('myads/{id}/delete', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\VehicleController@deleteOneAd',
]);
```

but when I click delete button and conform javascript message to delete records it is not working. I mean It is not deleting.

**myads blade file**
please see myads blade view

```
@forelse( $vehicles as $vehicule )


                    @if( $vehicule->uploads->count() > 0 )
                        <a href="{{ route('vehicles.show', $vehicule->id) }}">
                            @php
                                $upload = $vehicule->uploads->sortByDesc('id')->first();
                            @endphp
                            <img src="/images/{{ $upload->resized_name }}"></a>
                            {{$vehicule->provincename}}
                          {{$vehicule->milage}}
<br>

                           <td><a class="button is-outlined" href="{{route('vehicles.edit',$vehicule->id.'/edit/')}}" >Edit</a></td>
                            <td><a class="button is-outlined" href="/myads/{{$vehicule->id}}/delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to want to delete this record?')" >Delete</a></td>
                        </a> 
                        <hr>
                    @endif

            @empty
                <td>No Advertisment to display.</td>
            @endforelse
```

Comment: show me your error screen when you click the conform button to delete.

Comment: No, any error only redirect to back (refresh)

Comment: check request $id is correct in deleteOndeAd function

Comment: how can I do this?

Comment: Comment out `return redirect()->back();` and replace it with `return $id;`. More importantly, if you're not sure how to echo data out, you definitely need a tutorial on PHP.

Comment: In your edit button link you have an incorrect spelling. It should be `$vehicle` not `$vehicule`.

Comment: @AmirhosseinDZ No I have it as following  @forelse( $vehicles as $vehicule )

Comment: @John. Look at the code you shared. You have `/myads/{{$vehicule->id}}/delete/`, notice you spelling of **vehicule**. Are you sure that's right?

Comment: @snh yes it is ok

Comment: Ok so have you checked that the correct ID is being passed through yet?

Comment: No, an idea about that. how can I do that please?

Comment: Read up, I already replied to that question: "Comment out return redirect()->back(); and replace it with return $id;. More importantly, if you're not sure how to echo data out, you definitely need a tutorial on PHP."

Comment: pleasee see my myads blade file it is include my edit buttons

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('myads/{id}/delete', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\VehicleController@deleteOneAd',
]);
```

you should add `/` before `myads/{id}/delete`
by simply adding `/` at beginning of any url it becomes absolute url and can be accessed to absolute place from any place for example if you are at localhost:8000/home page and you clicked to the link where `myads/{id}/delete` is linked it will redirect to `localhost:8000/home/myads/{id}/delete` which will generate conflict to route you had mentioned in your route and give unwanted results.

Comment: did it but not success same thing here

Comment: it will be more easier to identify problem in the code if you post your error output too.

Comment: use 'return back()->withInput();' instead 'return redirect()->back();' for more http redirects goto [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183446/discussion-between-bhandari-and-john).

Comment: simply do `return back()->withInput();` it will redirect to same page after action is done mentioned in conrtollers method

Comment: it is not printing any thing here